# VB.NET Isogram checker

Tags: vb.net, module

I have this question here below. I am unable to figure it out.
any help would be much appreciated with an explanation on how its done too.

In VB, write a function called Isogram that takes in one parameter - a string of lowercase letters and returns a Boolean depending on whether or not the parameter is an Isogram. An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or nonconsecutive.

Assume that the string parameter is all lower case letters with no punctuation or numbers or spaces.

I have not been given any code at all, however I have had a shot. I know it is completely wrong however.

Here is my code:

```
Module Module1

    Function isogram(ByVal StringToCheck As String)
        For i = 0 To StringToCheck.Length - 1
            If Not Char.IsLetter(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next

        Return True
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim temp As String
        Dim x As Boolean
        Console.Write("Please enter a string: ")
        temp = Console.ReadLine()

        x = isogram(temp)

        Select Case x
            Case True
                Console.WriteLine("True")
            Case False
                Console.WriteLine("False")
        End Select

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We will be happy to help you, but you should have to do something to solve the problem. Do you have written some code to accomplish the task that your teachers have given to you? If yes then show it. If we just write the code for you we are not helping you at all even if we try to explain it step by step, indeed it would be rather unethical to give you an answer while your classmates are working to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65902451/edit) this question and include what you have tried.

Comment: Ive edited it with what i have currently tried

Comment: Your isogram function seems to be only checking if each character is an alpha character, you might have to re work your function a little to check if each character contains the letter where the count > 1